# Bar Chart Hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink, charts

I want to create a hyperlink for my bar chart (The whole chart is clickable and links to another page).

Is there any way of doing this without using MapArea?

Comment: Can you post the code for your current attempt?  Also, I guess it's safe to assume this is ASP.NET?

Comment: Why do you **have** to use MapArea class? In System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace, the Chart class has Click event which you can use to your liking.

Comment: Did you ever get past this? It does appear that adding labels to the chart (and generating an image map behind-the-scenes) imposes troubles on hyperlinking charts (though it appears to only conflict with IE, FF will follow the link without any issues.)